# Send Form Data containing inputs and files with JQuery & AJAX to PHP Web Service

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send all data from my form with Jquery and Ajax to a PHP REST webservice.

**JS**

```
$("#idform").submit(function(event) {

/* Stop form from submitting normally */
event.preventDefault();

//Get Data
var form = $(this),  
formData = form.serialize(),
formUrl = form.attr('action'),
formMethod = form.attr('method');

/* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
$.ajax({
    url: formUrl,
    type: formMethod,
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    //processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
    //contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    success: function(res){
        if (res.result == '0') {
                $("#idform").html('<div class="text-lg">Good Job!</div>');
            } else {
                //$("#respuesta").html('Error:');
                $("#respuesta").html(res.message);
            }     
    },
    error:function(res){
        $("#respuesta").html('Error comunicating webservice');
    }
});
```

});

**PHP**
I'm doing something like this with files:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 
$fileuploaded = $_FILES['fileuploaded']['tmp_name'];
$destinationpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/".$_FILES['fileuploaded']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($fileuploaded, $destinationpath);}
```

Everythings go ok when I make POST from form directly to php file but not when I'm trying to send data with ajax. PHP web service recieves all inputs but no my two files :(

Sorry for bad written english!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the JS like this

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "web_service.php",
        data:'value1=1&value2='+$("#num").html()+'&value3=G',
        cache: false,
        async : true,
        type: "POST",
        ....
```

In doc.php you have the code to connect to web service in PHP and the parameters send in the data line above. The data is an example